# Calculate days between two dates given specific values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a dataframe `df1`, and I want to calculate the days between two dates given three conditions and create a new column `DiffDays` with the difference in days.

1) When `Yes` is `1`

2) When values in `Value` are non-zero

3) Must be `UserId` specific (perhaps with `groupby()`)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['02.01.2017', '03.01.2017', '04.01.2017', '05.01.2017', '01.01.2017', '02.01.2017', '03.01.2017'],
                   'UserId':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'Value':[0,0,0,100,0,1000,0],
                   'Yes':[1,0,0,0,1,0,0]})
```

For example, when `Yes` is 1, calculate the dates between when `Value` is non-zero, which is 05.01.2017 and when `Yes` is 1, which is 02.01.2017. The result is three days for UserId in row 3.

Expected outcome:

```
        Date    UserId  Value   Yes  DiffDays
0   02.01.2017  1        0.0    1    0
1   03.01.2017  1        0.0    0.0  0
2   04.01.2017  1        0.0    0.0  0
3   05.01.2017  1        100    0.0  3
4   01.01.2017  2        0.0    1    0
5   02.01.2017  2        1000   0.0  1
6   03.01.2017  2        0.0    0.0  0
```

I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow about this, and not sure how to start.

Comment: The difference between which two dates..?

Comment: @MarkWang the difference the dates when the three conditions above are met. When `Yes` is 1, calculate the dates between when `Value` is non-zero, which is 05.01.2017 and when `Yes` is 1, which is 02.01.2017. The result is three days for UserId in row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dayDiff(groupby):
    if (not (groupby.Yes == 1).any()) or (not (groupby.Value > 0).any()):
        return np.zeros(groupby.Date.count())

    min_date = groupby[groupby.Yes == 1].Date.iloc[0]    
    max_date = groupby[groupby.Value > 0].Date.iloc[0]
    delta = max_date - min_date
    return np.where(groupby.Value > 0 , delta.days, 0)


df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, dayfirst=True)
DateDiff = df1.groupby('UserId').apply(dayDiff).explode().rename('DateDiff').reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([df1, DateDiff], axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
Date    UserId  Value     Yes       DateDiff
0   2017-01-02  1   0      1          0
1   2017-01-03  1   0      0          0
2   2017-01-04  1   0      0          0
3   2017-01-05  1   100    0          3
4   2017-01-01  2   0      1          0
5   2017-01-02  2   1000   0          1
6   2017-01-03  2   0      0          0
```

Although this answers your question, the date `diff` logic is hard to follow, especially when it comes to the placement of the `DateDiff` values.

**Update**

`pd.Series.explode()` was only introduced in `pandas` version `0.25`, for those using previous versions:

```
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, dayfirst=True)
DateDiff = (df1
            .groupby('UserId')
            .apply(dayDiff)
            .to_frame()
            .explode(0)
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            .rename(columns={0: 'DateDiff'}))
pd.concat([df1, DateDiff], axis=1)
```

This will yield the same results.

Comment: I get error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode' when trying your suggestion. I cannot find any information about function `explode`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Mataunited18 I updated the answer, `pd.Series.explode` was only introduced in `pandas` version `0.25`, either you update or you can use my updated solution that works around it.

Comment: Thanks it worked for my example. However, I get the error of "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" for my real data set, which means that `iloc[0]]` looks up something that doesn't exist. Do you know the solution to my problem?

Comment: @Mataunited18 I updated the answer to address yours, however,  you shouldn't extend the scope of a question with more questions, you should ask a new one instead, for example, how to detect a `df` mask returned nulls, check the following [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers).

Comment: @Mataunited18 Consider accepting the answer if it met your inquiry.